# Is this a christian symbol?

Tags: symbolism, cross

Can someone tell me which sect this comes from, if any?
It's from the back of a book or folder used by an Officiant in a wedding video.

Thanks!![image]

Comment: We might be able to handle a question like this, but you've given no context at all. Were is the image from? Where have to seen other than that source? Do you have any ideas, showing an effort to answer the question yourself?

Comment: Where did the wedding take place? What city/country? What was the name of the church, if any?

Answer (score 5):

The symbol is a coat of arms, probably from Catholicism, Anglicanism, or perhaps, but less likely, Orthodoxy. The mitre indicates that it was used by a Bishop, but not a Pope, as a Pope's coat of arms would include keys. The coat of arms of the British Bishop, [Thomas Burns](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_j3jEs0gnE-U/TR3-QPMMNeI/AAAAAAAAAcA/QwjrHNYBKOY/s400/burns%2B5.jpg) contains similarities: the mitre on the top, the two devices from the mitre down the sides, and the motto at the bottom where this coat of arms appears to have three Greek letters.

The source of the image would probably give some indication of exactly which Bishop had this coat of arms.

Comment: Thanks @brasshat all I know is it's from the back of a book or folder used by an Officiant in a wedding video...I'm not sure if that helps any.

Comment: The letter look like "AGW" to me. The A could be an Alpha, but the G is Roman/Latin and the W, if smaller and not paired with the other letters, might pass for a lowercase omega, but I don't think so. This said, I'm pretty sure they are Roman/Latin letters.

Comment: SB, it would help to know the location at which the wedding occurred. Fredsbend, when I looked at them earlier, I at first thought they looked like Greek letters, but Latin is possible, too.